# Error in Update child record EF Core 3.0 The association between entities has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required'

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, savechanges, ef-core-3.0

I'm using *EF Core version: 3.0* Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

I have two tables: **PROFILO** (master) and **PROFILOTITOLODISTUDIO** (details)
this is the model:

**PROFILO MODEL**

```
 public partial class Profilo
{
    public Profilo()
    {
        ProfiloTitoloDiStudio = new List<ProfiloTitoloDiStudio>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid IdProfilo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Cognome { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("IdProfiloNavigation")]
    public virtual IList<ProfiloTitoloDiStudio> ProfiloTitoloDiStudio { get; set; }
}
```

**PROFILOTITOLODISTUDIO MODEL**

```
public partial class ProfiloTitoloDiStudio
{
    [Key]
    public int IdProfiloTitoloDiStudio { get; set; }
    public Guid IdProfilo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string DenominazioneCorsoStudio { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(IdProfilo))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Profilo.ProfiloTitoloDiStudio))]
    public virtual Profilo IdProfiloNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

The **IdProfilo** foreign key in the **PROFILOTITOLODISTUDIO** table **must be NOT NULL**

In the controller's Edit action I receive the object with the fields bounded by the view as an input, even if I don't change any value, the **savechanges** () always returns the error:

> InvalidOperationException: The association between entities 'Profilo' and 'ProfiloTitoloDiStudio' with the key value '{IdProfilo: 45c42779-39b6-4047-91d1-12253a79b7f6}' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.

this is the save code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Profilo profiloinput)
    {


            var _profiloDB = await _dbcontext.Profilo
                                               .Include(p => p.ProfiloTitoloDiStudio)
                                               .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.IdProfilo == profiloinput.IdProfilo);

            _profiloDB.Nome = profiloinput.Nome;
            _profiloDB.Cognome = profiloinput.Cognome;


            _profiloDB.ProfiloTitoloDiStudio = profiloinput.ProfiloTitoloDiStudio;


            var x = await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();


    }
```

I am not breaking any relationship between **PROFILE** and **PROFILOTITOLODISTUDIO** I am simply trying ***to make an update on the child table***, the IDPROFILO foreign key in the profile object.ProfiloTitoloDiStudio is perfectly enhanced !!!

Answer (score 3):

I solved, in some posts this solution was reported but it was not very clear, the problem arises from the setting of the relationship between the two tables, the setting set in the class of the **DbContext**:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
```

this is the affected portion of code: ***BEFORE***

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProfiloTitoloDiStudio>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.IdProfiloTitoloDiStudio)
                .HasName("PK_TitoloDiStudio");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdProfiloNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProfiloTitoloDiStudio)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdProfilo)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ProfiloTitoloDiStudio_Profilo");

        });
```

this is after the change:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProfiloTitoloDiStudio>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.IdProfiloTitoloDiStudio)
                .HasName("PK_TitoloDiStudio");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdProfiloNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProfiloTitoloDiStudio)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdProfilo)
                /*.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)*/
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ProfiloTitoloDiStudio_Profilo");

        });
```

in practice the setting on the relationship **.OnDelete** was changed from **DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull** to ***DeleteBehavior.Cascade*** which would then be the default setting, so I removed it.

My difficulty is that the MyDbContext class was generated by Scaffold-DbContext (DatabaseFirst) so I prefer not to modify it, therefore I modified the relation directly on the DataBase and made Scaffold-DbContext turn around !!!

[image: this is the change on the DB]

tx to BombaAnarchica